# How the grep '[p]rocessname' ignores the 'grep' process in 'ps -ef'?

Tags: linux, unix, grep

When I am trying to find out the specific process by using `ps -ef | grep 'processname'`, it is giving `grep` process also.

Like this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'sleep'
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
root     25316  6114  0 18:08 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=always sleep
```

For that, I usually use `ps -ef | grep '[p]rocessname'` and this has been suggested by many websites and links in SO. Now, I am getting expected output.

```
$ ps -ef | grep '[s]leep'
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
```

My question is,

How the `grep '[p]rocessname'` ignores the `grep` process?

Because, When I redirect the output to some file and doing the `grep`. But, This time it gives me two line. I get confused. Here, What I have tried.

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'sleep' > input.txt

$ grep 'sleep' input.txt 
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
root     25689  6114  0 18:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=always sleep

$ grep '[s]leep' input.txt 
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
root     25689  6114  0 18:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=always sleep

$ cat input.txt  | grep '[s]leep'
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
root     25689  6114  0 18:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=always sleep
```

What is the difference between `ps -ef | grep '...'` and `grep '...' file` ?

Comment: Because the default `grep` matches regular expressions. If you matched with fixed strings, with `grep -F`, you would get the opposite output: just `[p]rocessname`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is an easy trick.

say you have only two `java` processes running on your machine, no other processes. with your `ps -ef|grep java` you have 3 **processes**

```
java ...
java ...
grep java
```

and your grep gives you 3 **output** lines. because three lines match regex: `java`

but if you do it with `grep '[j]ava'`,   you have these 3 **processes**:

```
java...
java...
grep [j]ava
```

The last line won't match regex `[j]ava`, it matches `\[j\]ava`, that's why your `grep '[j]ava'`  filtered the last process out, thus only 2 **output** lines

Answer (score 0):

When you try to do a normal search on all you see all process including your grep with the search pattern

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'sleep'
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
root     25316  6114  0 18:08 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=always sleep
```

When you use `ps -ef | grep '[p]rocessname'` , you will be getting the expected output.

```
$ ps -ef | grep '[s]leep'
root     25309 16242  0 18:08 pts/17   00:00:00 sleep 300
```

Using that regex you are launching a process which its ps string will not match itself, since the regexp matches "sleep" and not "[s]leep". That way you'll exclude the process that has the string "[s]leep" which in this case is grep; The same can be applied to pgrep, egrep, awk, sed, etc... whichever command you used to define the regex.

From man 7 regex

> A bracket expression is a list of characters enclosed in "[]". It
>   normally matches any single character from the list (but see below).
>   If    the  list  begins  with  '^', it  matches any single character
>   (but see below) not from the rest of the list.  If two characters in 
>   the list are  separated by '-', this is shorthand for the full range
>   of characters between those two (inclusive) in the collating sequence,
>   for example,  "[0-9]" in ASCII matches any decimal digit.  It is
>   illegal(!) for two ranges to share an endpoint, for example, "a-c-e".